# How to stop program to "END" word

Tags: python

So My program works perfectly when using ctrl+d in pycharm's standard input.
It gets the data from standard input. The problem is that my task is that
stop the program when I write "END" word in the last line.
It doesnt work and i don't know why.
Anyone can help me?

```
from collections import namedtuple
from typing import NamedTuple
import sys

LegoSet = NamedTuple ("LegoSet",
                      [("number", int), ("name", str),
                       ("theme", str), ("pieces", int)])


def line_to_lego_set(line: str):
    ls = line.strip().split(";")
    return LegoSet(int(ls[0]), ls[1], ls[2], int(ls[3]))


def lego_set_to_line(lego_set: LegoSet):
    return f"{lego_set.name} ({lego_set.number}): {lego_set.pieces} - {lego_set.theme}"


def sort_lego_sets(list):

    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(list)):
            if list[i][3] < list[j][3]:
                list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]
            elif list[i][3] == list[j][3] and list[i][2] > list[j][2]:
                list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]
            elif list[i][2] == list[j][2] and list[i][1] > list[j][1]:
                list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]
            elif list[i][3] == list[j][3] and list[i][0] > list[j][0]:
                list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]

    return list


def main():
    lego_sets = []
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if line == "END":
            break
        else:
            lego_set = line_to_lego_set(line.strip())
            lego_sets.append(lego_set)

    lego_sets = sort_lego_sets(lego_sets)

    for lego in lego_sets:
        print(lego_set_to_line(lego))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: the line might contain carriage return characters and not be exactly "END".  You should either use `line.startswith("END")` or `line.rstrip() == "END"`

Comment: You forget to add '\n' to "END" or you can change your condition into "END" in line

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you type `END` and press `ENTER` the actual line is not only `END` it is `END\n` on Linux or `END\r\n` on Windows.The `\n` and `\r\n` are a newline characters. To make your code work you have to change this if statement to:

```py
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if line.rstrip() == "END": # add here line.rstrip()
            break
        else:
            lego_set = line_to_lego_set(line.strip())
            lego_sets.append(lego_set)
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: 1) what if your system is configured to add "\r\n" when you press enter?

Comment: But it is not, i wrote about this example, not "\r\n"

Comment: Let's hope the OP is not on a Windows machine, otherwise 1) will not work.

Comment: Oh you are right, because in Linux new line character is "\n" but in Windows it is "\r\n" then the 1st example will not work